# add a record on the fly SQL Server2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I would like to create an additional row to a select statement however can not seem to figure out how to do this. Let's say I have a table that has 5 rows with the numbers 1 through 5 in them.

I do a `select * from tblname` to return 5 rows. Is it then possible to code something to create a 6th row with the number 6. Making sure that the number 6 appears regardless of where clauses ect.

It may sound odd but there is a reasoning behind it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tblname
UNION ALL
SELECT 6, <fill-in-other-columns>
```